Unable to get queue messages from rabbitmq in Spring project
I am trying to get my application to consume messages from rabbitmq queue but after a message has been added to the queue my application does not consume it and the logs does not show anything.
This is a spring project using the Axon framework
UserEventHandler.java
package com.jasper.ecommerce.query.handler;

import com.jasper.ecommerce.query.model.UserReadModel;
import com.jasper.ecommerce.query.query.FindAllUsersQuery;
import com.jasper.ecommerce.query.repository.UserRepository;
import com.jasper.ecommerce.shared.events.UserCreatedEvent;
import org.axonframework.eventhandling.EventHandler;
import org.axonframework.queryhandling.QueryHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class UserEventHandler {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserEventHandler(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    // Event handler for UserCreatedEvent
    @EventHandler
    public void on(UserCreatedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("UserCreatedEvent received: " + event);
        // Convert event to read model and save it in MongoDB
        UserReadModel user = new UserReadModel(event.getUserId(), event.getName(), event.getEmail());
        userRepository.save(user);  // This inserts the document into MongoDB
    }

    // Query handler to return all users
    @QueryHandler
    public List<UserReadModel> handle(FindAllUsersQuery query) {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}

AxonAMQPConfiguration.java
package com.jasper.ecommerce.query.config;

import org.axonframework.config.EventProcessingConfigurer;
import org.axonframework.extensions.amqp.eventhandling.DefaultAMQPMessageConverter;
import org.axonframework.extensions.amqp.eventhandling.spring.SpringAMQPMessageSource;
import org.axonframework.serialization.Serializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AxonAMQPConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SpringAMQPMessageSource rabbitMQMessageSource(Serializer serializer) {
        return new SpringAMQPMessageSource(
                DefaultAMQPMessageConverter.builder()
                        .serializer(serializer)
                        .build()
        );
    }

    public void configure(EventProcessingConfigurer configurer, SpringAMQPMessageSource rabbitMQMessageSource) {
        configurer.registerSubscribingEventProcessor("UserEventHandler", c -> rabbitMQMessageSource);
    }
}


application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: ecommerce-cqrs-query
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/ecommerce-query
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest

axon:
  amqp:
    exchange: AxonExchange
  eventhandling:
    processors:
      UserEventHandler:
        mode: subscribing
  axonserver:
    enabled: false
  distributed:
    enabled: false

logging:
  level:
    org.axonframework: DEBUG
    org.springframework.amqp: DEBUG
    com.rabbitmq: DEBUG

server:
  port: 8080


Note that the default name of a processor is the package name of the classes containing the event handlers. That way, classes inside the same package are automatically assigned to the same processor.
If you change your event processor configuration to:
configurer.registerSubscribingEventProcessor("com.jasper.ecommerce.query.handler", c -> rabbitMQMessageSource);

It should start consuming from RabbitMQ.
